# Clone repository with all branch from a remote repository with GitPython

Tags: python, gitpython

I'm trying to make a little program for my users for basic action for git and other. And I face a lot of problems to clone a private remote repository.

I have the following configuration :
Python 3.4
Windows
GitPython
Ssh connection etablished on the remote server.

Here is my code :

```
print(blue + "Where to clone repos ?")
path_repo = input(cyan + "> " + green)
try:
    assert os.path.exists(path_repo)
except AssertionError:
    print(red + "Path does not exist")
continue
print(blue + "Name of Repos :")
name_repo = input(cyan + "> " + green)
remote_path = "git@dev01:/home/git/repos/{0}.git".format(name_repo)
local_path = "{0}/{1}".format(path_repo, name_repo)
# Repo.clone_from(remote_path, local_path)
repo = Repo.clone_from(remote_path, local_path)
#print(repo.git.fetch())
#print(repo.git.pull())
#print(repo.git.status())
```

That doesn't raise error but the script stop at the end and blocks the terminal (give me infinite empty line without `>>>`)

After run that, if I go in Git Bash and type `git status` he seems to have no branch created, just init. So I add the 3 last lines of my code to see what is changed, but nothing.

If in Git Bash I type `git pull`, he pull well the master branch...

If somenone can resolve my problem please ?

Where I've make an error ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues with the code and the approach you describe...

**One**

First of all, you have

```
continue
```

written right in the middle of your code... So I assume that the code you provided is in some loop. All the code after unconditional `continue` in a loop is dead code - it will never be executed.

Therefore, it seems that you never actually clone anything...

**Two**

To see all branches are in a repo, please use something like `git branch -va`. I'm afraid that `git status` is not made for that.

**Three**

Since you seem to already have an initialized repo somehow, you will not be able to clone to the same location - because cloning creates the repo.

**Four**

Also, there is no point in checking if the directory exists - because `git clone` creates the directory if it doesn't exist.

---

To sum up, try this simple code below. I have commented out the line that would have probably resulted in an error due to the fact that the repo already exists.

```
print(blue + "Where to clone repo?")
path_repo = input(cyan + "> " + green)
print(blue + "Name of repo:")
name_repo = input(cyan + "> " + green)
remote_path = "git@dev01:/home/git/repos/{0}.git".format(name_repo)
local_path = "{0}/{1}".format(path_repo, name_repo)
#repo = Repo.clone_from(remote_path, local_path)
repo = Repo(local_path)
info = repo.remote('origin').fetch()
if not info:
    print('no fetch information')
for i in info:
    if i.note:
        print('fetched, note is: ' + i.note.strip())
    else:
        print('fetched, no note')
```

Comment: As far as I can see, you didn't finished answering the question; how to get `--all` passed to the `git clone` command.

Comment: When I do this: `$ git clone --` (press tab 2 times here) I get this:
`--bare            --local           --no-hardlinks    --reference       --template=
--branch          --mirror          --origin          --shared          --upload-pack
--depth           --no-checkout     --quiet           --single-branch` so as you can see option `--all` does not show up. And when I try to force it:

`$ git clone --all
error: unknown option \`all'` ... there is no such option. More info here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone So, what do you want to achieve by giving non-existing option to `git clone`?

Comment: Also, there is nothing about the `--all` flag in the original question. Anyway, what would you need it for? Git fetches all remote branches by default, and then if you need any of them you just do `git checkout some-branch`. If it doesn't exist, but `origin/some-branch` exists, a new branch `some-branch` will be created, checked out, and will be tracking origin.

Comment: The fact that tab completion on your shell does not provide an option does not really imply that the option does not exists. On the other hand, you're right, there is no `--all` option for `clone`, and I was mistaking it for the option for `push` and `pull`.